# Значения по умолчанию для полей в БД

Tags: mysql

Есть поле типа `int` которое может иметь а может не иметь значение.

Какое значение по умолчанию будет правильнее использовать в данной ситуации?

NULL нельзя,а если 0 то это может быть `primary key` в другой таблице.

Comment: _NULL нельзя,а если 0 то это может быть primary key в другой таблице_ - вот это поподробней бы узнать, что вы задумали. Раз у вас это поле должно ссылаться на другую таблицу, то было бы логично сделать `foreign key` ссылающийся на ту таблицу, но тогда NULL это единственно верное решение, как раз он может быть в колонке и не нарушать `foreign`

Comment: У меня есть таблица отделов и юзеров, при добавлении нового юзера он может не состоять в отделе,поэтому по умолчанию какое то значение нужно! А на счет Null к интовому типу разве правильно использовать?

Comment: Абсолютно правильно. NULL колонки при хранении вообще в innodb хранятся одним битом в заголовке страницы. Причем в теле записи при этом 4 байта int не хранятся, запись становится короче. И по идеологии реляционных БД NULL введен специально для таких случаев. Ну и опять же `foreign key` надо бы сделать что бы в базе было невозможно включить при ошибках в программе сотрудника в несуществующий отдел или удалить отдел в котором есть сотрудники

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Раз у вас таблица (T1) хранит некое значение, которое в другой таблице (T2) является `primary key`, то установка некого специального значения отличного от `NULL` и не находящегося в T2 это странное решение. Оно конечно имеет право на жизнь, но используется в очень экзотических случаях.

В базах данных, при связи двух таблиц, значение `NULL` как раз используется для отражения факта отсутствия какого либо значения и, следовательно, необходимости такой связи у записи.

В реляционных базах данных рекомендуется делать внешние ключи (`foreign key`) для отражения связи двух таблиц. Наличие такого `foreign` призвано для обеспечения [ссылочной целостности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) БД. Он не позволяет существовать в подчиненной таблице значениям, не существующим в основной таблице. При этом внешний ключ позволяет существовать `NULL` значению - как раз для отражения факта отсутствия связи.

Рекомендуемая структура таблиц (Отделы и сотрудники):

```
create table DEPT
(
   DEPT_ID              INT not null auto_increment,
   DEPT_NAME            VARCHAR(100),
   primary key (DEPT_ID)
) engine = InnoDB;

create table PERSON
(
   PERSON_ID                   INT not null auto_increment,
   NAME                 VARCHAR(100) not null,
   DEPT_ID              INT,
   primary key (ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (DEPT_ID)
      REFERENCES DEPT(DEPT_ID)
) engine = InnoDB;
```

При отсутствии у сотрудника отдела к которому он относится `DEPT_ID` должен быть `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `-1` так как в auto_increment его не будет

Comment: Спасибо,тоже склонялся к этому варианту!